# Control Android Java Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my Android App there is an activity that contains a runnable inner class.
From this activity a new Thread running the inner class is created/started.
This thread executes this loop:

```
while (run) {
  ...
}
```

The state of the boolean "run" should be changed from both threads.
Thats why I put it into the activity class like this:

```
private static volatile boolean run;
```

I would like to know if this is a correct way of controlling a thread.
Do both threads use the same variable in the memory?
As neither checking nor setting a boolean is an atomic operation for the cpu, is it possible, that one thread checks "run" while the other thread is changing its state?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Could it be solved in some other (perhaps better) way?

Comment: Checking *or* setting a `boolean` is atomic.  Checking *and* setting a `boolean` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do both threads use the same variable in the memory?

Yes.  You haven't shown us much code, but since the variable is `static`, you've shown us enough.  A `static` variable only exists in one place.  Any code that can see it anywhere in your program is seeing the same variable.

> I would like to know if this is a correct way of controlling a thread.

It is a fine way of *signalling* a thread.

The only reason why you might want to do differently is if the thread is not able to check the `run` variable often enough.  Especially, if the thread *waits* for anything.

In that case, you might want to look into `thread.interrupt()`  Interrupting any thread while it is waiting for something (in most cases) will cause the method that was waiting to throw an `InterruptedException.`  That affords your thread the opportunity to check whether or not it still should be running.

Answer (score 1):

A thread will stop itself if the task you placed in the inner `Runnable` class was completed. So, keeping the `Runnable` alive will make the thread alive too, i.e. using `while` loop. And `volatile boolean` controls the change of `run` variable easily.